# Why this code no longer work in 7.1?

Tags: objective-c, xcode5

```
UITextField * textField= self.textField;
textField.background = [UIImage resizeableImageWithCapInsets2:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 7, 0, 7) withName:@"Search-Field"];
```

Simple code.

```
2014-03-13 09:31:02.099 isikota[179:60b] -[BGSearchBar setBackground:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17566b20
2014-03-13 09:32:17.720 isikota[179:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[BGSearchBar setBackground:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17566b20'
```

It doesn't make sense. Clearly background is a property of textField

I found out that the problem is I use this:

```
-(UITextField *) textField
{
    UIView * textFieldView = [self findASubViewWithProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)];

    return (UITextField *)textFieldView;
}
```

This seems to be no longer the way to get a textField from UISearchBar. How to do so then?

I think the problem is since 7.1 `[UISearchBar conforms to UITextInputTraits]`

Also I wonder why

```
return (UITextField *)textFieldView;
```

doesn't return a run time error because now textFieldView is no longer a subclass of UITextField

Comment: The error says `textField` is a `BGSearchBar`.

Comment: I know. Looks like since 7.1     UIView * textFieldView = [self findASubViewWithProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)]; return the uisearchbar.

Answer (score 2):

I've always done it like this:

```
for (UIView* v in self.searchbar.subviews) {
    if ([v isKindOfClass: [UITextField class]]) {
        return v;
    }
}
```

Or, in iOS 7:

```
for (UIView* v in [self.searchbar.subviews[0] subviews]) {
    if ([v isKindOfClass: [UITextField class]]) {
        return v;
    }
}
```

Does that not work any more?

Comment: You have to admit that their refusal to allow direct access to the text field inside the search bar is kind of silly. We know it's in there somewhere!

Comment: I like your second solution better.  A recursive algorithm would be even more resilient, since `subviews[0]` might become `subviews[1][0]` in a future update.

Comment: @AaronBrager Neither of those two are recursive. Both are simple loops that only check a single level of subviews. Both are likely to break someday.

Comment: @rmaddy Correct.  I'm saying a recursive algorithm would be better.

Comment: @AaronBrager Oops. I see that now. I misread your comment. Yes, a full blown recursive search through the full subview structure would be best. But there is still the possibility that Apple could replace the text field with something that doesn't actually extend `UITextField`. Matt is right - why doesn't Apple give us more ability to customize the text field?